# get-ADuser - pipe to delete home directories of disabled users

Tags: powershell

Looking for doe help to pipe the below command into a command to automatically delete all home directories.

The below command lists al users that are disable in AD and their home directories.

```
Get-ADUser -filter 'enabled -eq $false' -properties Name, homedirectory -SearchBase "OU=Avanta_UK,OU=_Avanta_Group,DC=avanta,DC=co,DC=uk” | ft Name, enabled, samaccountname, homedirectory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously run this with caution:

```powershell
Get-ADUser -filter 'enabled -eq $false' -properties Name, homedirectory -SearchBase "OU=Avanta_UK,OU=_Avanta_Group,DC=avanta,DC=co,DC=uk" | % {
    Write-Host ("Removing homdir for:" + $_.Name + ",path:" + $_.homedirectory)
    rm -Force -Recurse $_.homedirectory
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will narrow the search first and do a test :)